# Staging: frontend works fine, backend shows login but after login 404

Tags: backend, login, 404

I've made a staging-area for my Magento shop (magentodir.nl URL is example and not real :) )
Structure:

- Live-store: magentodir.nl
- Staging-store: magentodir.nl/staging

Staging front-end (staging.magentodir.nl) works perfectly but the backend give me the headaches. staging.magentodir.nl/admin shows me the admin-login page. However when I login it shows me the 404 error - Whoops, our bad... and this in my store-design and colors

Comment: are you using any protection software which blocks your ip after certain amount of different logins? Did you try login in using a proxy server?

Comment: No there is no protection software what so ever. I didn't try a proxy server and I don't know how to use that?

Comment: https://hide.me/en/proxy just go there and try to login your backend using the URL and then see if it works. Also change your password afterwards in case it works

Comment: No with a proxy I also get a 404 error

Comment: Can you try to set the staging up new or is it a working environment already? Maybe setting it up new will be less time consuming if its a new setup

Comment: I already did a complete new setup but sadly with the same results

Comment: Maybe check that for the database, only thing i could think of now
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178066/error-404-not-found-in-magento-admin-login-page